# Cancel Jquery Accordion close if condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have an accordion that on load gets data using ajax to fill it starts getting autoupdates. Then on close I unload the data and removes it from autoupdate list.

But the user can open an Edit page in the accordion, and if this page is open the user should get a warning if he tries to close the accordion e.g. (Closing this will cause you to loose all none saved data) or similar.

So I want to "intercept" the accordion toggle close event and if certain data (The edit page) is loaded inside the accordion a "are you sure" warning should popup.

Comment: pasting some code does not kill kittens

Comment: Which accordion component are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
   changestart: function(event, ui) { 
     ...
     if (dataInvalid) {
       return false;
     }
   }
});
```